# MongoDB distinct and Sort

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I'm have one problem with app.

when i call sort method it runs ok, but when i call distinct it returns undefined when i call both returns sorted but doesn't call distinct.

```
controller.listaClientes = function(req, res) {    

var filtro = {};

Cliente.find(filtro)    
.sort([['regional', 'desc']])

.exec()
.then(
  function(listagem) {
    res.json(listagem);
  },
  function(erro) {
        console.log(erro);
        res.status(500).json(erro);
      }   
);
```

};

So I'm continuing a project and it is using moongose.

Somebody can help me?

Comment: Can you give an example of your `distinct` call?

Comment: From the Mongoose docs, **sort** cannot be used with **distinct**: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html

Answer (score 0):

The Mongoose docs state that **sort** cannot be used with **distinct**:
[mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html)

You could try to perform the query using **distinct** and then use the JavaScript **sort** method on the returned array.

Perhaps something like this:

```
Cliente.find(filtro)    
  .distinct('field') // Amend to desired field
  .exec()
  .then(function(listagem) {

    // Sort the returned array here
    listagem.sort(function(a, b) {
      // Assuming 'listagem' is an array of objects
      // ...where you want to sort on the 'regional' property
      return a.regional < b.regional;
    });

    res.json(listagem);

  },function(erro) {

    console.log(erro);
    res.status(500).json(erro);

  });
```